# FusionCharts-Security warning

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

Hello all I have implemented Fusioncharts and it works fine on my local host , but when I deployed to our staging server for testing, when we run a page that has the charts I get the security warning:

Im Using the Javascript charts like so for example:

```
var myChart = new FusionCharts("../js/FusionCharts/MSColumn3D.swf", "myChartId", "450", "450", "0", "1");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the link below,

[http://forum.fusioncharts.com/topic/12495-security-warning-using-javascript-charts/page_*p*_49444_*hl*_security+warning_*fromsearch*_1#entry49444](http://forum.fusioncharts.com/topic/12495-security-warning-using-javascript-charts/page__p__49444__hl__security+warning__fromsearch__1#entry49444)

Hope this helps!